# NSSound stop function

Tags: objective-c, nssound

Thanks for the help.

This activates basic playback of referenced file:

```
NSSound *sound = [[NSSound alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ping" ofType:@"aiff"] byReference:NO];

[sound play];
```

What's the proper way to terminate playback? No luck implementing the following:

```
NSSound *sound = [[NSSound alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ping" ofType:@"aiff"] byReference:NO];

if([sound isPlaying])  {
    
    [sound stop];
```

Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Is `sound` in `[sound stop]` the same `NSSound` instance as in `[sound play]`?

Comment: Thanks, and yes - it is, albeit the functions are implemented in discrete actions.

Comment: If the answer solves the issue then no, `sound` in `[sound stop]` was not the same `NSSound` instance as in `[sound play]`.

Comment: Yes. I stand corrected ... thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the couple code snippets you included in your question, it *looks* like you are doing this:

```
// create new sound object
NSSound *sound = [[NSSound alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ping" ofType:@"aiff"] byReference:NO];
// start it playing
[sound play];
```

and then you ***create another new*** sound object:

```
// create new sound object
NSSound *sound = [[NSSound alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ping" ofType:@"aiff"] byReference:NO];

// this cannot be true - you just created the sound object
if([sound isPlaying])  {
    [sound stop];
}
```

Try this very simple example (just add Play and Stop buttons to a view controller and connect them):

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController() {
    NSSound *sound;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // instantiate sound object with file from bundle
    sound = [[NSSound alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"1162" ofType:@"aiff"] byReference:NO];
}

- (IBAction)playClicked:(id)sender {
    if (sound) {
        [sound play];
    }
}
- (IBAction)stopClicked:(id)sender {
    if (sound && [sound isPlaying]) {
        [sound stop];
    }
}

- (void)setRepresentedObject:(id)representedObject {
    [super setRepresentedObject:representedObject];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Got it all working. Again, thanks.